# Dropbox Synchronous interrupts

Tags: android, dropbox, interrupt

In my Android app, when the following code is successful:

```
mDbxAcctMgr.startLink(SyncActivity.this,REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
```

This code runs:

```
if (ds.getSyncStatus().hasIncoming) {

                    try {

                        Map<String, Set<DbxRecord>> mMap = mDatastore
                                .sync();

                        dataHasIncoming(mMap); // Inserted into the database

                    } catch (DbxException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


        }
```

If you close the app while this is occurring, `dataHasIncoming(mMap)` just inserts *part* of the data, but loses the rest. Is there any way around this,  such as setting a node, or re-opening the synchronization without checking all the data?

Comment: Do you mean you killed the app while `dataHasIncoming` was running and it didn't get to finish processing everything in `mMap`? What does `dataHasIncoming` do?

Comment: yes, dataHasIncoming // Inserting mMap into the database

Comment: Ok, so this is more about Android application lifecycle and making sure your app can finish certain tasks before being killed, as opposed to anything specific to Dropbox, so this is a bit outside my area of knowledge.

Comment: Maybe the lifecycle documentation here would be helpful: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Comment: If there are 5000 data has been processed 2000, this time synchronous interrupts, then how do I start from the position of 2000 Resume

Comment: Can I set a synchronization node at position of 2000